# get the user id from user meta in WordPress using the custom meta key

Tags: wordpress

I need to get the subscribers user details based on the selection in the filter for this i have tried the below code

```
    $status = join('","',$status); 
        $distribusjon = join('","',$distribusjon); 
        $qrys = '
            AND (

                (utrop_usermeta.meta_key = "status" AND  utrop_usermeta.meta_value IN ("'.$status.'")) OR
                (utrop_usermeta.meta_key = "mepr_distribusjon" AND  utrop_usermeta.meta_value IN ("'.$distribusjon.'")) 
            )   

        ';

$users = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT DISTINCT(ID) FROM '.$wpdb->users.' u LEFT JOIN '.$wpdb->usermeta.' m ON m.user_id = u.ID WHERE 1 AND ID IN ( SELECT user_id FROM '.$wpdb->usermeta.' WHERE 1 '.$qrys.') AND meta_key = "utrop_capabilities" AND  meta_value REGEXP "[[:<:]]s:10:\"subscriber\";"');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method.
List all users:

```
$users = get_users();
```

Filter for role (ex. subscriber):

```
$users = get_users('role=subscriber');
```

Exclude for id user:

```
$users = get_users('exclude=1');
```

And You can filter by [WP_User_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/)

```
$query = new WP_User_Query( 
    array(
        'role'          => 'Your_role',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'Your_custom_meta_key',
                'value'   => 'Your_meta_value',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    ) 
);

$users = $query->get_results();
```